# Getting intersection of lists, beginning with the same string

Tags: python, list

I am searching for elements in one list that begin with the elements in the second list

```
lis = [x for x in LL if any(x.startswith(i) for i in RR)]
```

**This gives me the correct results**, however i need to get a list containing the strings from both the LL and RR lists (preferably in a tuple).

(if this sounds odd, because one might think that they would look the same, in this case they do not)

This only gives me the results from list LL

Any suggestions on how to get the results from LL accompanied by the match that was found in RR ?

Comment: you mean you want string from LL that start with strings from RR and you mean you want string from RR that start with strings from LL?

Comment: Do you want only one match per `x`, or all of them?

Comment: @Ni - strings in LL that start with strings in RR.

Comment: @Blorgbeard one match per x as it will be a one to one match. missing in this explanation is that i use x.lower(), i.lower(). therefor the corresponding result in RR (startswith) will be the same word but different case. this is why i need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
from itertools import product
lis = [(x, y) for x, y in product(LL, RR) if x.startswith(y)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
lis = [(x,i) for x in LL for i in RR if (x.startswith(i))]
```